# Pinescript - How to create an alternation between entry signals and close or stop loss signals?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm trying to convert a strategy I made in tradingview in an indicator in order to allow the creation of alerts triggered by the signals of the indicator.
The problem is that it works but there isn't an alternation between entry signals and close or stop signals
I get multiple consecutive entry signals ora close and stop loss signals even if there isn't an active entry order
I've tried different ways like using a state variable to keep track of the active order but it doesn't work and I can't understand why

This is the code of the indicator. It is a channel breakout strategy. It enters the trade when the price goes above the max of the previous lenght candles and closes it when the price goes below the min of the previous lenght candles

```
//@version=5
indicator("Channel Breakout Indicator", shorttitle="CB Indicator", overlay=true)

length = input.int(title = "Length", minval = 1, maxval = 1000, defval = 5)
stop = input.int(title = "Stop loss (%)", minval = 0, maxval = 100, defval = 0)

upBound = ta.highest(high, length)[1] // Previous candle's highest value
downBound = ta.lowest(low, length)[1] // Previous candle's lowest value

var float entry_price = na

// Conditions for breakout signals
entryCondLong = ta.crossover(close, upBound)
entryCondClose = ta.crossunder(close, downBound)

if entryCondLong and na(entry_price)
    entry_price := close

if entryCondClose
    entry_price := na

// Stop loss for the long position
longStopLoss = entry_price * (1 - stop / 100) // Adjust the multiplier for the ATR according to your risk management
stopLossCond = ta.crossunder(close, longStopLoss)

// Plot breakout signals on the chart
plotshape(entryCondLong, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.blue, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(entryCondClose, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.yellow, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(stopLossCond, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)

// Alert for breakout signals
alertcondition(condition=entryCondLong, title="Long Breakout", message="Long Breakout Detected!")
alertcondition(condition=entryCondClose, title="Close Breakout", message="Close Breakout Detected")
alertcondition(condition=stopLossCond, title="Stop Loss", message="Stop Loss Detected!")
```